# C# HttpClient truncating URI during POST request

Tags: c#, rest, uwp, httpclient

I am trying to make a POST request in C# UWP app to a specific endpoint. The result I am getting is just the HTML from the home page. When looking at the request, I am specifying the whole endpoint, but when making the request, it is just hitting the host (without the endpoint).

I am trying to POST to: `http://ip-address/api/devices/logs`
The URI is POSTing to: `http://ip-address`

The code:

```
Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://ip-address/api/devices/logs");
var objClint = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage respon = await objClint.PostAsync(requestUri , new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(text), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
string responJsonText = await respon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I am meant to get back the result of the POST request (like the created object) but I am just getting the HTML from the home / landing page.

I have tried settings the `BaseAddress` of objClient and just passing through the rest of the end point, passing through the entire endpoint as the parameter in `PostAsync`, and adding `UriKind.Absolute`.

I really don't know what to do from here.

If I run `GetAsync` on the same URI, it doesn't shorten the Request URI and gives the right response.

What can I do from here?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion it is posting to http://ip-address ? _I'd say there is a 90% chance it is posting to the correct URL but your server side routing isn't working the way you think it should._ Please show us the source code for the GET and POST endpoints (server-side) if you have them available. If you don't, please point us to the documentation for them.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, should work as expected

Comment: What [StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.statuscode#System_Net_Http_HttpResponseMessage_StatusCode) is returned from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i test your code snippet, it works as expected.  Are you sure that POST is available at this route?  It's possible that the code is not truncating the URL and the return is simply a redirect.  I would check this first.

Either way, here is an alternative way of making your request with the same dependencies if you want to try it another way that also should work.

```
var baseUri = new Uri("http: //ip-address/");
var route = "/api/devices/logs";
using (var objClint = new HttpClient())
{
      objClint.BaseAddress = baseUri;
      var respon = await objClint.PostAsync(route, new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { text = "text" }), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```